# How to override cell component in react material table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend, material-table

I am using material table cellEditable in my project and I want to override cell component to  restrict users from entering negative no in the field. also, throw error validation. I am able to achieve that in "editable" but not on cellEditable How to achieve that??

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h1f8d?file=/demo.js:609-979

```
<MaterialTable
      title="Cell Editable Preview"
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      cellEditable={{
        onCellEditApproved: (newValue, oldValue, rowData, columnDef) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("newValue: " + newValue);
            setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
          });
        }
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to find how to restrict even an entry of a negative number, but I have been able to restrict saving it. Also this will throw an alert letting you know you're trying to save a negative number into the Year field.

```
onCellEditApproved: (newValue, oldValue, rowData, columnDef) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (columnDef.field === "birthYear" && newValue < 0) {
                alert("You entered a negative year....");
                return reject();
            }
            setData((prev) =>
                prev.map((item, i) => {
                    if (rowData.tableData.id === i)
                        item[columnDef.field] = newValue;
                    return item;
                })
            );
            setTimeout(resolve(), 1000);
        });
```

Note that this code will allow you to successfully update all other fields as well.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-x74m1?file=/demo.js